# Using Google Speadsheet API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

[Updated]

I am trying to use Google Spreadsheet API to automate our reporting process (which is being handled manually). I have created Service Account and downloaded a json file.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def create(title):
    """
    Creates the Sheet the user has access to.
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
        """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        spreadsheet = {
            'properties': {
                'title': title
            }
        }
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                                    fields='spreadsheetId') \
            .execute()
        print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
        return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pass: title
    create("mysheet1")
```

Here is the result:

```
TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google_auth_httplib2._Response object at 0x7f262a34fd90>)
```

[image]

It's strange that there is no code lines to receive access to Google Work Space (like connect to API using keys?)

AFTER SETTING UP OAUTH CLIENTS ID

Now I am facing new problem. After running the code, It asked me to "**Please visit this URL to authorize this application: with a link**", I clicked and got this message: "**This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect**".(I am running the code on Colab)

Comment: it doesn't need `API key` in code because it reads it from your JSON file

Comment: Have you set the credentials in your environment?

Comment: @furas do you mean the part right here: creds, _ = google.auth.default()

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=sOm9PFrT8mGG Colab has the example to interact with google sheets

Comment: They have recently added consent screen to use google apis: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent

You'll need to add it as specified

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the spreadsheet API ?

https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

I suspect it's because you have not given it the scope:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

def main():
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

- Where `credentials.json` is your file
- Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets
  You will also need to download the gcloud cli:

If you ever try to run it locally, on your windows/linux/mac machine.

`default credentials` are the credentials stored by either the default service account in google cloud or your local machine

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud

And run

`gcloud auth login`

Comment: Yeah both Drive and Spreadsheet APIs are enabled. I am running it on Google Colab. What do I have to download?

Comment: Sorry I have not seen that you were running in google Colab.
 I have created Service Account and downloaded a json file.